# Find the norm of operator $S:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$, $(Sx)(z)=z\int_{0}^{1}x(t)dt$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I'm suspecting that $||S||=1$. Beacause $$ ||S(x)||_{\infty}=\sup_{z\in [0,1]}\left|z\int_{0}^{1}x(t)dt\right| =\sup_{z\in [0,1]}|z|\cdot \left|\int_{0}^{1}x(t)dt\right|\leq ||x||_{\infty}.$$
Hence, $||S||\leq 1$. Now, if we show that $||S||\geq 1$, then $||S||=1$. So I imagine that it remains to show that $||S||\geq 1$.

Comment: What happens you when you look at $x(t)\equiv 1$?

Comment: Thanks! I understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Pick $ x(t) = 1$ $\forall t \in [0,1]$ and you get the complete result.

Comment: Thanks my friend!