# Calculate the operator norm defined with the dependency on the function f(t)

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E=F=G=C^0([0,1])$ all three endowed with the norm $||\cdot||_\infty$ of the uniform convergence defined as $||x||=\max_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)|$.

Let $f\in C^0([0,1])$ fixed with $f(t)\geq0 \ \forall t\in [0,1]$. We consider operators $T\in\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ and $S\in\mathcal{L}(F,G)$ which are defined as $(Tx)(t)=f(t)x(t)$ and $(Sx)(t)=f(t)\int_0^1x(t)\ dt$

*(it has been suggested that the integral upper bound from apparently should be changed from $1$ to $t$, another guess that it should be defined as $(Sx)(t)=f(t)\int_0^1x(r)\ dr$)*

and want to calculate the norms $||T\circ S||$ and $||S\circ T||$.

First of all, I am a bit confused with that function $f(t)$. I know that the composition of linear operators is just a multiplication. Also in this particular case I guess that the order of multiplication doesn't matter and we have $||T\circ S||=||S\circ T||$ but I am not sure, is it true here? In general it is not true but I wonder when it is. Do I need to explicitly compute the norms and find the bounds for the $||T\circ S||$ or I just can use $||T\circ S||\leq||S||\cdot||T||$ and produce from that?

upd. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060189/find-the-norm-of-operator-sc0-1-rightarrow-c0-1-sxz-z-int-01x) is the problem which can help to calculate the $||S||$

Comment: You can't have $t$ be both the variable of integration and have it be defined outside of the integral, did you make a typo in the definition of $S$?

Comment: I checked again the exercise and unfortunately I didnt make a typo. Maybe prof did it

Comment: if f(t) is under the integral sign then it would be just the integral operator, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm guessing it's meant to be $f(t) \int_0^t x(s) \mathrm{d}s$, but who knows.

Comment: and I guess $||S||$ should be $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\int_0^1 f(t) \ dt$?

Comment: @BrunoB thanks I've edited the initial problem taking into account your advice

Comment: You still need to name the integration variable differently from $t$, but yeah I think it's probably the best guess I can come up with. Yours wouldn't have been farfetched if it weren't for $S$ then going to $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $E$.

Comment: Thank you, no  $S: F\to G$

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $S$ is defined by $S : x \in E \mapsto \left(t \mapsto f(t) \int_0^t x(s)\mathrm{d}s\right) \in E$, though the answer doesn't really change much otherwise.

We then have $T \circ S \neq S \circ T$ iff $f$ is nonconstant, as $(S \circ T)(x)(t) = f(t) \int_0^t f(s)x(s)\mathrm{d}s$ yet $(T \circ S)(x)(t) = f(t)^2 \int_0^t x(s)\mathrm{d}s$.
In both cases though, the norms will be less than $\|f\|_\infty^2$, either by looking at them directly or by using that $\|T \circ S\| \leq \|T\|\|S\| \leq \|f\|_\infty^2$ (same for $S \circ T$) like you said.

Of course this is always only an inequality and doesn't have to be an equality: take for example a non-zero matrix $A$ such that $A^2 = 0$, then we have $\|A^2\| = 0 \neq \|A\|^2$.
This means that yes, you need to explicitly compute the norms, using better inequalities to get better bounds.

As a hint, here $x \equiv 1$ works perfectly for both applications, lucky for us. Can you take it from there?

Comment: I will try to hold the initial problem since in fact things do not change a lot. 
 
$||S\circ T||=\sup|f(t)\int_0^1 f(s)x(s)ds|\leq^{1} f(t)(\int_0^1 |f(s)|^2ds\int_0^1 |x(s)|^2ds)^{1/2}\leq^{x=1} \sup \{ f(t)||f(t)||_2 \}$

$||T \circ S||=\sup|f(t)^2\int_0^1 x(s)ds| \leq \sup\{ f(t)^2\}$

1. by Cauchy-Schwarz

but it anyway seems not correct